# Sliding in android

Tags: android

If you have installed most of mediaplayers like files managers like ES File Explores, users that touches the screen and move to left or right, the pages moves to left or right. That is exactly like build in android music player for 2.3, when user next music. How can I implement  this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using a `ViewPager` widget. Note that its part of the compatibility library so it can be used from API4 and above. Otherwise, you could always implement all this manually.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: @Ata: No, by `ViewPager` I mean `ViewPager`, added link to the reference in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking of the `ViewPager` widget. This is available in the Android Support Package, as K-ballo described. Titles/tabs are not included by default, however... if you want your pages to have titles or tabs (i.e. the Google Play store), you can check out Jake Wharton's [`ViewPagerIndicator`](http://viewpagerindicator.com/).

Comment: Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator is almost a must. +1